# Angular router conseguir url con token

Tags: angular

En mi aplicación tengo un modo de recuperación de contraseña en el cual me llega al mail una url con este formado

dominio.com/recuperar_password?token=DFDSEWEWEWKDWS

la vista recuperar_password ya la tengo en mi vista angular routing creada pero al pone ?token=EFDSDSDSFSD no funciona logicamente :/

```
path: 'recuperar_password/:token', component: CambiarPassword },
```

Comment: que no te funciona? no te carga el componente o no puedes acceder al `token` que esta en la url?

Comment: No le carga el componente

Comment: puedes poner como los tienes definido en el `routing`?

Comment: ahí lo aregué, gracias!

Comment: Una pregunta, Miguel como fue que solucionaste tu problema? Tengo que hacer algo igual pero no logro mandar nada sobre el url, omito el placeholder pero de igual manera no logro enviar nada, se va como null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas confundiendo `queryString` y `parametros de ruta`. En angular y en muchos otros frameworks cuando se define el routing para componentes o vistas se pueden definir "placeholders" para esperar valores en la ruta y así hacer que las rutas sean dinámicas.

Por ejemplo,

```
/miruta/:id/:name
```

Para que angular haga el match de la ruta y renderize el componente la ruta tiene que tener un `id` y `name` sino no se rendedriza porque no hay match.

En tu caso, no necesitas un "placeholder" para `token` ya que es un `queryString`. Y estos son valores que van luego de `?`.

Por ejemplo,

```
/miruta?token=abcd123&id=12314
```

Para arreglar tu error, tienes que quitar el placeholder `:token`. Y en tu componente en el `ngOnInit` capturar el `queryString` `token`.

```
{ path: 'recuperar_password', component: CambiarPassword },
```

En CambiarPassword

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnOnit() {
   this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
     this.token= params.token;
   });
}
```

Comment: Me dice que la propiedad token no existe en params.token, en el constructor cree un public token:string;

Comment: pon `params: any` o puedes crear un modelo para el tipado `interface CambiarPasswordParams { token: string; }` y poner `params: CambiarPasswordParams`

Comment: Muchas gracias @hawks voy a ponerlo ahora mismo